# [api](Unsplash Api) trying to generate random pictures for my testing database

Tags: javascript, node.js, api

I'm using a nodejs package called [casual](https://www.npmjs.com/package/casual) Which basically lets one generate random data

Im defining this method for generating imgs

```
casual.define('portrait', () => ({
 uri: `https://source.unsplash.com/collection/9948714?sig=${casual.integer(1, 100)}` 
}));
```

From this, I create an array of images like this :

```
[
  {"uri":"https://source.unsplash.com/collection/9948714?sig=37"},
  {"uri":"https://source.unsplash.com/collection/9948714?sig=32"},
  {"uri":"https://source.unsplash.com/collection/9948714?sig=91"},
]
```

I'm supposed to get a different image each time, but the PROBLEM is that I get the same picture 3 times, even with the `sig`.

What I'm I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

[SOLVED]

```
casual.define('portrait', () => ({
 uri: `https://source.unsplash.com/collection/9948714?${casual.integer(1, 100)}` 
}));
```

generating

```
[
  {"uri":"https://source.unsplash.com/collection/9948714?37"},
  {"uri":"https://source.unsplash.com/collection/9948714?32"},
  {"uri":"https://source.unsplash.com/collection/9948714?91"},
]
```

just adding a number instead of `sig=number` worked